# Location Error 'Google play services is not available', react native

Tags: react-native, location, android-gps

In my application, I am using `react-native-geolocation-service` to get location updates.
For IOS application it works just fine, but for the android application It gives me this error 
I have enabled permission and all, here is the watcher

```
this.watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      position => {
        //   this.setState({ location: position });
        // console.log(position);
        console.log('got position ')
        console.log(position)
        this.dispatch({
          type: UPDATE_LOCATION,
          location: position
        })
      },
      error => {
        //   this.setState({ location: error });
        console.log('error occured')
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
        console.log(error);
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        distanceFilter: 0,
        interval: 10000,
        fastestInterval: 5000
      }
    );
```

No matter if i run the app in an emulator, or a android device error stays the same.
Code is just working fine for ios

Answer (score 0):

In options parameter create **ternary**. Check mobile Platform, if Android - empty brackets, else - receive object like you need. Something like this:

`Platform.OS === 'android' ? {} : { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 10000  }`